# How to hide existing page in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have web application which have some web pages. Now I want to hide them when some attribute in my configuration will be false. With hide them I mean when someone write web page address there will be status not found. Is this possible in wicket ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can throw an `AbortWithHttpErrorCodeException` in your page:

```
public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {

   if(someConditionToHidePage) {
      throw new AbortWithHttpErrorCodeException(404, "page not found");
   }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. You could build a custom Link component that get disabled if the attribute in your configuration it's false.